# SQL 片方のテーブルにのみ存在するデータを抽出したい

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

### 前提

2つのテーブルのうち片方にしか存在しないデータを抽出したい
自身でも考えましたが、一向に進まないのでお力添えをお願いします。

### テーブル

テーブルA

| company | image_file1 | image_file2 | image_file3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 竹中不動産 | 000.jpg | 301.jpg | 002.jpg |
| 竹中不動産 | 050.jpg | 501.jpg | 032.jpg |
| 三葉不動産 | 110.jpg | 161.jpg | 112.jpg |
| ベニエル不動産 | 220.jpg | 221.jpg | 222.jpg |

テーブルB

| company | file_name |
| --- | --- |
| 竹中不動産 | 000.jpg |
| 竹中不動産 | 301.jpg |
| 竹中不動産 | 002.jpg |
| 竹中不動産 | 050.jpg |
| 三葉不動産 | 110.jpg |
| 三葉不動産 | 112.jpg |
| ベニエル不動産 | 220.jpg |

期待する結果

| company | image_file1 | image_file2 | image_file3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 竹中不動産 |  | 501.jpg | 032.jpg |
| 三葉不動産 |  | 161.jpg |  |
| ベニエル不動産 |  | 221.jpg | 222.jpg |

テーブルAは各レコードが１つの物件情報
1つめの竹中不動産の場合
竹中不動産が所有する物件で画像が3枚あることを表す

### 自分で考えたこと

```
SELECT campany, image_file1, image_file2, image_file3
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN table b
ON
```

までは考えたのですが、この後が続きません
そもそも上記の途中までのクエリ自体まちがっているかも・・・

Answer (score 1, accepted):

テーブルBに`file_name`が存在しない項目のみ`image_fileX`を表示する目的ならば、下記のSQLで実現可能です。

```
select *
from   (select A.company
              ,nullif(A.image_file1, B1.file_name) as image_file1
              ,nullif(A.image_file2, B2.file_name) as image_file2
              ,nullif(A.image_file3, B3.file_name) as image_file3
        from   A
        left outer join B as B1 on B1.company = A.company and B1.file_name = A.image_file1
        left outer join B as B2 on B2.company = A.company and B2.file_name = A.image_file2
        left outer join B as B3 on B3.company = A.company and B3.file_name = A.image_file3
       ) T
where coalesce(image_file1, image_file2, image_file3) is not null
```

テーブルAの`image_fileX`とテーブルBの`file_name`をそれぞれ左外部結合して、両カラムが存在する場合は`nullif`関数で`null`にしています。

`nullif`関数は[PostgreSQL](https://postgresweb.com/how-to-use-the-nullif-function)にも[SQLite](https://www.javadrive.jp/sqlite/function/index25.html)にも存在するので、どちらのデータベースでも同じ結果が返ります。

**実行結果**

| company | image_file1 | image_file2 | image_file3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 竹中不動産 |  | 501.jpg | 032.jpg |
| 三葉不動産 |  | 161.jpg |  |
| ベニエル不動産 |  | 221.jpg | 222.jpg |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oAYMn3M8UBLsiDPYDXppUd/1)